# HTTPS using cURL, using openssl with the capi engine

Tags: c, curl, openssl

I'm attempting to use https using cURL 7.21.1 with OpenSSL 1.0.0d, using OpenSSL's builtin capi engine for certificate authority checking, but it returns CURLE_SSL_CACERT (60) on curl_easy_perform().

```
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/engine.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#define CURL_NO_OLDIES
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <curl.h>

// Don't forget libeay32.lib, ssleay32.lib, curl.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "wldap32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    OPENSSL_no_config();
    ENGINE_load_capi();
    // Same effect, despite ok = 1 both times:
    // ENGINE* capi = ENGINE_by_id("capi");
    // int ok = ENGINE_init(capi);
    // ok = ENGINE_register_complete(capi);

    CURLcode e = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

    e = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/");
    e = curl_easy_perform(curl); // returns CURLE_SSL_CACERT
    return 0;
}
```

If I test "openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443" with the following config:

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
engines = engine_section

[engine_section]
capi = capi_config

[capi_config]
engine_id = capi
init=1
```

based on http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg62249.html, I receive:

```
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

The thing that is confusing me, is that when I first wrote the actual program this is failing in, it had the same failure until I added ENGINE_load_capi().
I would like to avoid using a CA bundle, since the actual program may be running inside random corporate networks, and they might be using private CAs.

Comment: Are doing this on a windows platform?

Comment: @this.josh: Yeah, I know I can't use CryptAPI on other platforms, but *nix based ones could use the platform ca-bundle.crt, right? I'll probably just end up bundling it anyway for reliability if nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like OpenSSL is having an issue finding the default certificate store? The following SO question resolved a similar error by specifying the CA file explicitly, but it sounds like you'd like to avoid that configuration.

[OpenSSL unable to get local issuer certificate unless CAfile is explicitly specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041512/openssl-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-unless-cafile-is-explicitly-speci)

Comment: I believe we did end up doing this, but yeah it still sucks. I will take a look at it to see what we did but we are not likely to touch it any time soon

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to add the following line in your file on which you have access the domain.
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);