# unable to get local issuer certificate in fresh image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, openssl

I have created a fresh Docker image:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential g++ curl openssl libssl-dev apache2-utils git libxml2-dev sshfs libbz2-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libffi-dev libreadline-dev libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev

# Install Python
RUN curl -L https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/raw/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash
RUN echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bash_profile && \
    echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile && \
    echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile && \
    echo 'eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN source ~/.bash_profile && \
    pyenv install 3.7-dev && \
    pyenv virtualenv 3.7-dev venv && \
    pyenv global venv && \
    pip install -U pip
```

However, after running this in a container, I am unable to access any websites due to a certificate issue. This is happening both in Python (3.6 & 3.7) and openssl:

```
openssl s_client -connect discordapp.com:443
openssl s_client -connect python.org:443
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443
```

All return the same error: `Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)`

In Python, it gives me (when `discord.py` tries to connect to `discordapp.com`:

```
SSL handshake failed on verifying the certificate
protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x7fd78479c6d8>
transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport fd=6 read=polling write=<idle, bufsize=0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.7-dev/lib/python3.7/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 625, in _on_handshake_complete
    raise handshake_exc
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.7-dev/lib/python3.7/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.7-dev/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 763, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1048)
SSL error in data received
```

I attempted to update my certificates with `apt-get install ca-certificates`, but the command states that this package is already up to date.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's the full error you're seeing when running the Python code?

Comment: Updated to include the python error.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691327/ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-ssl-c/41692664)?

Comment: Those solutions seemed to be aimed at Mac OS X. I am not finding an equivalent solution that works in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try it, please.

```
openssl s_client -connect python.org:443 -verify false -debug
```

If you want to disable the verification, use the command I write above.

> **-debug** is optional.

I think this is a duplicated topic because the problem is not in docker, but in OpenSSL console syntax.

Check this: [OpenSSL unable to get local issuer certificate unless CAfile is explicitly specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041512/openssl-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-unless-cafile-is-explicitly-speci?rq=1).

Actually, you have to find your **-CApath directory**. Your certificates are there.

You will need a generic CAcert too, so visit this site:
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html.

Hope it will be helpful.
Good luck.

Comment: Why would I want to bypass certificate verification?

Comment: Feel free to do what you want.
I present a solution if you want to bypass, or a solution to fix the certs. Check the first link.